# Como generar un json de un objeto que viene de forms.ModelForm

Tags: python, json, django, python-3.x, formularios

Hola quisiera crear y guardar un objeto en la base de datos el cual tiene argumentos `args` y `kwargs`. los argumentos `args` y `kwargs` deben obedecer al formato `JSON`, tengo lo siguiente:

```
class ProgramarActividadForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Mymodel
    fields = '__all__'
    widgets = {
        'nombre': forms.TextInput(attrs={
            'type' : 'text',
            'placeholder' : 'Nombre de la Tare ',
            'class': 'form-control'}),

        'tarea':forms.Select(attrs = {
            'class' : 'form-control',
            }),

        'usuarios_envio':forms.Select(attrs = {
            'class' : 'form-control',
            }),

        'grupo_envio':forms.Select(attrs = {
            'class' : 'form-control',
            }),

    }
```

Los campos `usuarios_envio` y `grupo_envio` están de la siguiente forma en los modelos:

```
usuarios_envio = models.ForeignKey('Usuarios.User')
grupo_envio = models.ForeignKey('auth.group')
```

En mi `view.py` tengo algo como esto:

```
def form_valid(self, form):

    task = ObjectTask(
        name= form.cleaned_data['nombre'],
        task=form.cleaned_data['tarea'],            
        args=json.dumps(form.cleaned_data['usuarios_envio']),
        kwargs=json.dumps({form.cleaned_data['grupo_envio']})
    )
    task.save()
    return super(ProgramarActividadView,self).form_valid(form)
```

Guardar las variables normales no causa problemas pero cuando el argumento es un objeto, en este caso para `args` y `kwargs` me dice que no se puede serializar.

**Error:**

> `<User: Administrator> is not JSON serializable`

---

**Actualizacion:**

Se prueba la primer solución que proponen

```
kwargs=json.dumps({'msjtxt': form.cleaned_data['usuarios_envio'].__dict__,})
```

Pero ahora se obtiene un error:

> PhoneNumber is not JSON serializable

porque como se observa:

```
usuarios_envio = models.ForeignKey('Usuarios.User')
```

hace referencia a un modelo `User` y ese modelo tiene un atributo:

```
celular_gsm = PhoneNumberField(blank=True, help_text=help_text_number)
```

Ya probé la siguiente solución:

```
kwargs=json.dumps({'msjtxt': form.cleaned_data['usuarios_envio'].values(),})
```

Pero obtengo un error porque `User` no tiene el atributo `Values`

Luego probé lo siguiente:

```
kwargs=json.dumps({'msjtxt': form.cleaned_data['usuarios_envio'].__dict__.values(),})
```

Y me manda el siguiente error:

> dict_values([PhoneNumber(country_code=52, national_number=1234567890, extension=None, italian_leading_zero=None, number_of_leading_zeros=None, country_code_source=1, preferred_domestic_carrier_code=''), PhoneNumber(country_code=52, national_number=1234567890, extension=None, italian_leading_zero=None, number_of_leading_zeros=None, country_code_source=1, preferred_domestic_carrier_code=''), 'Centrales', '123213', '', False, 2, 'IngOM', 'materno', 'Paterno', True, None, 'user@user.com.mx', , PhoneNumber(country_code=52, national_number=123456789, extension=None, italian_leading_zero=None, number_of_leading_zeros=None, country_code_source=1, preferred_domestic_carrier_code=''), datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 7, 18, 6, 43, tzinfo=), 'Raul', '12312313', False]) is not JSON serializable

Comment: ¿Que es `ObjectTask`, es un modelo tuyo? Me parece raro que estes usando específicamente `args` y `kwargs`. ¿Estás seguro de estar usando correctamente el modelo? En todo caso pega el código que realmente estás usando

Comment: Si. por el momento ObjectTask es modelo mio como prueba, realmente quiero utilizar un modelo que provee Celery (PeriodicTask) el cual tiene esos atributos args y kwargs pero solo acepta datos en formato json.

Answer (score 1):

efectivamente, no puedes serializar directamente objetos que derivan o representan un modelo. para hacerlo debes convertirlo a un diccionario y luego serializarlo. no indicas en que parte sucede exactamente la excepción. así que asumo lo siguiente:

```
def form_valid(self, form):

    task = ObjectTask(
        name= form.cleaned_data['nombre'],
        task=form.cleaned_data['tarea'],            
        args=json.dumps(form.cleaned_data['usuarios_envio'].values()),
        kwargs=json.dumps({form.cleaned_data['grupo_envio'].values()})
    )
    task.save()
    return super(ProgramarActividadView,self).form_valid(form)
```

edit:
tambien puedes usar el método "values" para obtener los valores atómicos de los campos. de esa forma si se pueden serializar todos los campos del objeto.

Comment: moscoquera, gracias. le diste solucion a la pregunta, pero ahora me tope con otro detalle que no pude solucionar: el modelo 'usuarios_envio' contiene un atributo PhoneNumberField y ahora no puede serializar PhoneNumber, como puedo serializar el atributo de un modelo que tambien voy a serializar?    args=json.dumps(form.cleaned_data['usuarios_envio'].__dict__)

Comment: acabo de actualizar la respuesta, en lugar de __dict__ puedes usar el metodos "values"

Comment: Gracias, ya he probado .Values() pero la verdad no se como utilizarlo,  kwargs=json.dumps({'msjtxt': form.cleaned_data['usuarios_envio'].values(),}) me manda el siguiente error 'User' object has no attribute 'value' ya busque poe google pero no logro corregir el error

Comment: Se actualiza pregunta!!